# Migrating from auth.User to custom user model. Groups and permissions are always empty

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-custom-user

I'm migrating my app from Django 1.4 to Django 1.7. I have already upgraded all third party libraries and Django itself. No errors and warnings on running `manage.py check` or when using `manage.py runserver`'.
Now I want to move to a custom user model. I have created the model and it's a direct copy of the User model from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` with one difference - I have created my own PermissionMixin base because with the default one the reverse relationships were clashing between the default User model and my custom User model.

```
class PermissionsMixin(models.Model):
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField('superuser status', default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group, verbose_name='custom_groups', blank=True,
        related_name="custom_user_set", related_query_name="user")
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission, verbose_name='user permissions', blank=True,
        related_name="custom_user_set", related_query_name="user")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_group_permissions(self, obj=None):
        permissions = set()
        for backend in auth.get_backends():
            if hasattr(backend, "get_group_permissions"):
                permissions.update(backend.get_group_permissions(self, obj))
        return permissions

    def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return _user_get_all_permissions(self, obj)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):

        # Active superusers have all permissions.
        if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
            return True

        # Otherwise we need to check the backends.
        return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)

    def has_perms(self, perm_list, obj=None):
        for perm in perm_list:
            if not self.has_perm(perm, obj):
                return False
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        # Active superusers have all permissions.
        if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
            return True

        return _user_has_module_perms(self, app_label)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('first name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('last name', max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('staff status', default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Until that point everything is fine - the migration creates the required tables in the database and I can modify the Custom user model in admin.
Now I want to copy all the data from `auth.User` to my `users.CustomUser` model with a datamigration. The below code reflects what I would like to do:

```
from django.db import migrations, transaction


@transaction.atomic
def copy_old_users(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("auth", "User")
    CustomUser = apps.get_model("users", "CustomUser")

    fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
              'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'is_superuser',
              'last_login']

    for user in User.objects.all():
        custom_user = CustomUser()
        for field in fields:
            setattr(custom_user, field, getattr(user, field))

        custom_user.save()

        custom_user.groups.add(*user.groups.all())
        custom_user.user_permissions.add(*user.user_permissions.all())

@transaction.atomic
def remove_new_users(apps, schema_editor):
    CustomUser = apps.get_model("users", "CustomUser")
    CustomUser.objects.all().delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0003_auto_20150128_1715'),
        ('users', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(copy_old_users, remove_new_users),
    ]
```

I am using MySQL. The problem here is `user.user_permissions.all()` and `user.groups.all()` are always empty. I have tried the same in the django shell - empty. In admin - the `groups` aren't properly attached and the `user_permissions` are. I have checked in the database - this should not be empty. Further investigation showed that the following code retrieves the required objects:
  `User._meta.get_field('groups').rel.through.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)`

and it's the same with `user_permissions`. I can iterate through the objects list from the above query and access the `Group` object to use it in my migration. This is all well and working.

Questions are: why doesn't the standard way work? Am I accessing the objects in some bad way? Have I missed something in data migration? Should I import(?!) some specific dependency or retrieve the `Permission` and `Group` models in some special way?

Comment: Can you post your custom user model?

Comment: @jbergantine I have edited the question with the user model.

Comment: I suggest you to bring this up to Django bug tracker.

Comment: Do you need to introduce the [`has_perm()` and `has_perms()` methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) perhaps? I've done a custom user model that defined those methods and just implemented `return True` for each one.

Comment: This might also be useful: http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/#comment-1056203268

Comment: A gist of `has_perm()` and `has_perms()` that I'm using: https://gist.github.com/jbergantine/cb3c0e1cd4c2df0b5587

Comment: @jbergantine I think you don't understand where the problem lies. I want to move permissions between user models, not mock them on the new user model. I am also able to do this successfully. As far as I have debugged the problem was that the manager on the groups and permissions was set to the new models, not the old ones, for the old User model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but if it's a one-time migration, I'd recommend doing a json dump of your `auth.group` and `auth.permission` models:

```
./manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 auth.group auth.permission > groups_and_perms.json
```

Then you can load them in again with:

```
./manage.py loaddata groups_and_perms.json
```

Also, groups and permissions would be `ManyToMany` relations, wouldn't they be? If that's the case, try using `.save_m2m()` in your `copy_old_users()` function:

```
custom_user.save()

custom_user.groups.add(*user.groups.all())
custom_user.user_permissions.add(*user.user_permissions.all())

custom_user.save_m2m()
```

Comment: I am not really sure what are you suggesting. I have defined the "other way round" solution in my question that is easier to implement than your solution and it does work. Also you don't need to call `save_m2m` if you are using `.add` - it does the saving for you.